# Why there's UpDown arrows image?

Tags: discussion

[image]

Why there's updown arrow images (see red circle). Is it indicating something?

Comment: Why there is no hand-drawn circle in your screenshot ?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Upvoting and downvoting are two of the very first and basic community moderation tools / privileges.

So, a set of up and down arrows was used as the icon for the "moderation" privilege type.

Comment: That's correct, but see up/down voting doesn't need of moderation privilege, a user with some few repo (I don't know exactly) can do this, right?

Comment: @Hemang: upvoting and downvoting is a form of community moderation.

Comment: @Hemang upvoting and downvoting is the most basic tool used for moderation of the site. It's not the same thing as *being* a moderator, but it's how we "moderate" questions -- meaning it's how we control quality.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, thank you so much for clarification :)

Comment: A small addition, because it was unclear to me from just this answer: [all moderator privileges](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges) have that same icon. It's not an icon specifically for protecting questions, it's shared with the other moderator privileges, including "vote up" and "vote down".